# Qt Blocking signals while loading something

Tags: c++, qt

I have a set of settings (some checkbox) and when I toggle it some file will load but while that file is loading i make that set of settings disabled and I am blocking their signals. But after my file is loaded and re-enable my widgets and signals somehow it triggers signal if I am trying to toggle one checkbox.

So my code its like this :

```
function (...)<br>
{
<br>DisableAndBlockSignals(true);
<br>LoadThatFile(); // it takes ~6 sec
<br>DisableAndBlockSignals(false);
<br>}
```

And if I toggle one checkbox from settings while is loading and all settings and signals are disabled it triggers my slot after loading.

edit: It's there any solution that when is loading i cannot trigger any checkbox ?

Comment: `But after my file is loaded and re-enable my widgets and signals somehow it triggers signal if I am trying to toggle one checkbox.` That's exactly what your code does. When you trigger it afterwards your signal is back enabled.

Comment: Do you load the file in a background thread? If not, the GUI thread might block during the loading and handle keyboard and mouse events after the function, when the signals are no longer block.

Comment: Disabling a widget is much more intuitive for the user than blocking its signals.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, your file loading blocks events. So the mouse click event is received only after this whole method returns.

Try this:

First disable this widget before you load file, or mybe parent or parent's parent or whole main window. All child widgets get disabled too.

Then load file.

Then call processEvents after file loading, so mouse events get delivered but do nothing. Note: if you do things wrong and the events cause this method to be called again, re-entered, you're in trouble,. But having widget disabled should make sure this does not happen.

Then enable the widget you disabled.

---

Note: If file loading takes this long, research QProgressDialog or using separate thread as a better solution.